# Automatically set the value of next in all django CBV

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, authentication

I want my website to work like this:

1. Attempt to go to a URL. (=>should become the 'next' parameter)
2. You get redirected to the login page, because you're not logged in.
3. After logging in, it should take you to 'next.'

Nobody has ever framed their usage of next in this manner, so far that I've seen on S.O. and the docs don't help at all. Everyone else asks how to redirect **if you click Login explicitly**.

Do I have to modify every single get_success_url() or get_context_data() method in every one of my CBV to properly give it the 'next' parameter? I can't even tell which view is actually saying "oh you're not logged in, go to /login/ ," cause if I could tell that I could at least attempt to override that method and give it the request.path parameter. I assume it is AuthenticationMiddleware, or LoginRequiredMiddleware

Apparently it isn't "LoginView" (django 1.11) because when I put a breakpoint on the dispatch method there, it doesn't see my original attempted URL anywhere, it simply sees

request.path = '/login/'

**How do I nab the value of "originally intended url" and set it to the 'next' parameter, so that it redirects to '/login/?next=next_page' instead of just '/login/** ?

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^login/$',
    login,
    {
        'template_name': 'login.html',
        'authentication_form': BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
        'extra_context':
        {
            'title': 'Log in',
            'year': timezone.now().year,
        },
    },
    name='login'),
url(r'^logout$',
    logout,
    {
        'next_page': 'login',
    },
    name='logout'),
```

If you want to see my login.html please just say so. I don't think it matters here though, as I don't have a problem passing 'next' as long as it is in in the **context** first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following middleware [TomasTomecek](https://gist.github.com/TomasTomecek/5056424)

```
# in settings.py

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = (
 r'^about\.html$',
 r'^legal/', # allow any URL under /legal/*
) 

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # ...
    'python.path.to.LoginRequiredMiddlewareFromTomasTomecek',
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I unfortunately can’t test this for a week cause of the holidays, but will try it out and report back first thing in January.

Comment: I had to edit the middleware a bit because it referenced my setting login_url in a weird way, but after that it works great! Thank you!